# Jquery button returns undefined

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to push parameters into an array with a jquery button (on click), but the console returns 'undefined'. Not sure why the input value isn't being referenced. Here is my code..

```
//JAVASCRIPT

let garage = [];

class Car{
  constructor( year, make, model ){
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  } //end constructor
} // end Car class
let newCar = new Car( $( '#yearIn' ).val(), $( '#makeIn' ).val(), $( '#modelIn' ).val() );
$( document ).ready( function () {
 $('#submitCarButton').on('click', function(){
   //console.log( $('#yearIn').val(this.year) );
    garage.push(newCar);
    console.log(garage);

 }); //end enterButton on click
}); //end document ready//


//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <title>Week 6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Garage Inventory</h1>
    <div id="garageDiv">

    </div>
    <p1>Enter car here</p1>
    <div id="carInput">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Year" id"yearIn" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Make" id"makeIn"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Model" id"modelIn" />
      <button id='submitCarButton'>Add Car</button>
    </div>

    <h2>Cars In the Garage</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

At one point I got it to say '#makeIn, '#yearIn etc...

Comment: You're instantiating your car with the values of the elements before any code actually runs. Move the `let newCar` line inside of your `$('#submitCarButton').on('click', function () {` function, before the `push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a few thing that needed to be fixed:

First, you are missing the '=' sign in the id attribure: (id"yearIn" should be id="yearIn")

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Year" id="yearIn" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Make" id="makeIn"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Model" id="modelIn" />
```

Secondly, you need to instantiate the newCar instance inside the click event so that every time you click add, a new instance will be added.

```
 $('#submitCarButton').on('click', function(){
   let newCar = new Car( $('#yearIn').val(), $('#makeIn').val(), $( '#modelIn' ).val() );
    garage.push(newCar);
    console.log(garage);

 }); //end enterButton on click
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b69xvozt/13/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing "=" with attribute id of the three inputs
it should be like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Year" id="yearIn" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Make" id="makeIn" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Model" id="modelIn" />
```